# How do I pre-configure a block's settings in my module in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, blocks, installation

I'm building up a custom module which contains a few blocks. These blocks will always only appear either on the front page or on every other page, mutually exclusive.

I'd like to be able to pre-configure these blocks on install, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  The documentation for [`hook_block_configure`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7) mentions an `'#options'` key, but has no details on the format of that info.

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the standard block options, you can do that in [`hook_block_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info
 */
function MODULE_block_info() {

  $blocks = array();

  // Assign block to front page, sidebar_first region by default
  $blocks['my_front_page_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Front page block'),
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'sidebar_first',
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => '<front>'
  );

  return $blocks;

}
```

Comment: I somehow missed that in the docs. My head is swimming learning Drupal, but its a pretty cool framework.  Thanks!